# Keeping one Leaflet sidebar open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, maps, leaflet

I'm working on a Leaflet map project with multiple markers that open their corresponding sidebars (markerA opens sidebarA, markerB opens sidebarB, etc.) This is what the code looks to accomplish this:

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar 1</h1>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-two">
    <h1>Sidebar 2</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
            closeButton: true,
            position: 'left'
        });
        map.addControl(sidebar);


    var marker = L.marker([51.2, 7]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        sidebar.toggle();
    });

    var sidebarTwo = L.control.sidebar('sidebar-two', {
        closeButton: true,
        position: 'left'
    });
    map.addControl(sidebarTwo);

    var marker = L.marker([52.2, 7]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        sidebarTwo.toggle();
    });
```

Now, I am using a [Leaflet sidebar plugin](https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/), and when I click on several markers at a time, the sidebars open on top of each other.

What I'd like to do is if you click markerA and sidebarA appears, you can click markerB, and it will close sidebarA and bring in sidebarB. I'd like for this to be interchangeable, so any marker will close the current one open bring in its own sidebar. Is this possible? I've included a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lno1a6nc/1/) to show what the basic map, markers and sidebar look like. **NOTE:** You'll need to stretch the demo window wider to see it on the default screen width.

The demo also includes the plugin's source code. I've fiddled with it and have a feeling this code snippet:

```
toggle: function () {
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            this.hide();
        } else {
            this.show();
        }
    },
```

Might be where my answer is. I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed writeup. I think @yarl's answer or something similar to that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close other sidebar inside onclick function:

```
    var marker = L.marker([52.2, 7]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        if(sidebar.isVisible())
            sidebar.hide();
        sidebarTwo.toggle();
    });
```